# Can't hotfix : SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement

Tags: react-native

I have the "well-known" error below, but I can't use the workaround suggested as a correction because the file initializeCore.js simply does exist.

How can I have a better stacktrace of the error please ?

Error + old workaround : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11389

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find Core directory as per the popular suggestion then you must be having an older version of RN. Do the same under:

node_modules\react-native\Libraries\JavaScriptAppEngine\Initialization\InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js